# Equivalence of two definitions of holomorphic functions.

Tags: complex-analysis, definition

I am a graduate student and studying complex analysis in the current semester.Our instructor follos the book Stein and Shakarchi for complex analysis in which the definition of holomorphic function is the following:

Let $ \Omega\subset \mathbb C$ be open and $f$ be a complex-valued function on $\Omega$.We say that $f$ is holomorphic at $z_0\in \Omega$ if $\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\frac{f(z_0+h)-f(z_0)}{h}$ exists and in this case we denote the limit by $f'(z_0)$.

But in other texts on complex analysis I found the following definition:

A function $f:\Omega\to \mathbb C$ is said to be holomorphic at $z_0\in \Omega$ if there is a neighbourhood $N(z_0,\delta)$ of $z_0$ where $f'(z)$ exists.

Clearly the second definition implies the first one but my question is whether the two definitions are equivalent i.e. whether the first one implies the second.Can someone give me a proof or a counterexample to justify that?

Comment: The first definition is what I know as *“$f$ is complex differentiable at $z_0$”* and the second is the usual definition of *“$f$ is holomorphic at $z_0$”.* The second implies the first, but not vice versa. A simple (well-known) example is $f(z) = |z|^2$ at $z_0 = 0$

Comment: Are you sure you are quoting the first definition correctly?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy: I have checked it in https://www.google.de/books/edition/Complex_Analysis/0ECHh9tjPUAC?hl=de&gbpv=1&dq=Stein+and+Shakarchi+complex+analysis&printsec=frontcover. – Apparently they call “holomorphic at a point” what other people call “complex differentiable at a point.”

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holomorphic_function and https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Analytic_function#Analytic_functions_of_one_complex_variable agree with *your* definition.